# "Cannot connect to remote desktop" with Citrix Receiver

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and 13.9.1 Citrix Receiver.

Whenever I try to launch .ica file, I'm getting

> Cannot connect to "0.0.0.2-Remote Desktop_"
>
> No such file or directory. Verify you connection settings and try again.

How can I resolve this issue?

[image: screenshot with pop up dialog]

Comment: @Jeff: The error message looks quite different though.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to "launch" that file? Looks like it may not be where you or the application expect it to be.

Comment: `cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/` then:
`rm -rf cacerts` and finally:
`ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts`

Comment: `cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/` then: `rm -rf cacerts` and finally: `ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts` fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: Hi, Ive been trying to solve this for the last two weeks with no success.  Ive tried all the above and i keep getting the same error.  Has anyone else tried some other solution?  Kubuntu 18.04 Citrix receiver 13.9.1.6